# Stop Karaf from generating new SSH keys on startup

Tags: ssh, apache-karaf

I've noticed that Karaf keeps generating new SSH keys on each startup. It makes automatic scripts connecting via ssh useless, because new key must be manually accepted each time.

Is it possible to stop that behaviour and generate new keys only once per new installation?

More debug info: I've noticed, that 'etc/host.key' has not changed. However, after stopping and starting karaf I get the message:

> ssh -p 8101 localhost -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss

```
Offending DSA key in ~/.ssh/known_hosts:5
  remove with:
  ssh-keygen -f "~/.ssh/known_hosts" -R [localhost]:8101
DSA host key for [localhost]:8101 has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

The fact that DSA keys are generated doesn't match the log message from karaf.log as well:

> INFO  | sshd-SshServer[20056f77]-nio2-thread-2 |
>   SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider   | 48 - org.apache.sshd.core - 1.2.0 |
>   generateKeyPair(RSA) generating host key - size=4096

My `etc/org.apache.karaf.shell.cfg`:

```
sshPort=8101
sshHost=0.0.0.0
sshRealm=karaf
hostKey=${karaf.etc}/host.key
algorithm=RSA
keySize=4096
```

After digging in logs I've found out, that host.key file is not loaded properly:

> 2017-03-29T13:44:58,977 | WARN  |
>   sshd-SshServer[18c17f90]-nio2-thread-1 |
>   SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider   | 48 - org.apache.sshd.core - 1.2.0 |
>   resolveKeyPair(~/karaf-docker/apache-karaf-4.1.0/etc/host.key) Failed
>   (InvalidKeySpecException) to load: Missing classes:
>   org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.BCRSAPrivateCrtKey
>   2017-03-29T13:45:00,340 | ERROR |
>   sshd-SshServer[18c17f90]-nio2-thread-1 |
>   SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider   | 48 - org.apache.sshd.core - 1.2.0 |
>   Overwriting key (~/karaf-docker/apache-karaf-4.1.0/etc/host.key) is
>   disabled: using throwaway ssh-dss:
>   SHA256:3yWwxdzoymMvEBYIWMIguQ8G3J7kfapd+avCMoue2R4
>   2017-03-29T13:45:00,342 | WARN  |
>   sshd-SshServer[18c17f90]-nio2-thread-1 | ServerSessionImpl

The Apache SSHD reads/writes host.key using Java Serialization which might cause issues in OSGi (and, maybe even worse, redeploy of feature might turn the file useless).

Comment: Keys should be created only once per installation. Do you have any special environment?

Comment: @ChristianSchneider I'm using version 4.1.0 on Ubuntu x86_64, using Oracle Java 1.8

Comment: Can you try to connect with just ssh -p 8101 karaf@localhost? .. strange I just tried with your command and still my key was created correctly.

Comment: @ChristianSchneider without that -o param I get error:
"Unable to negotiate with ::1 port 8101: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-dss"
I'm not giving user name because then the key from etc/keys.properties is used, but karaf@localhost give me the same error message.

Comment: It sounds like your ssh client does not accept RSA. Can you try to change the shell.cfg algorithm from RSA to DSA?

Comment: @ChristianSchneider I have RSA enabled. What SSHD implementation is using Karaf internally?

Comment: Karaf is using Apache Mina sshd. https://mina.apache.org/sshd-project/

Comment: @ChristianSchneider OK so one more question: is current snapshot version 4.1.2 fully compatibile with 4.1.0? After updating from 4.0.8 to 4.1.0 I've got to adapt the features I need to install. We've chosen karaf because of its high performance, but automatic setup makes a headache. Maybe we should need commercial support to setup the install/update scripts?

Comment: 4.1.2-SNAPSHOT and 4.1.1 are fully compatible. 4.1.0 was a bigger step and has some known incompatibilities. Automatic installs and updates are tricky. Getting commercial support is a good idea to start. You can also try on the karaf user list for advice.

Comment: @ChristianSchneider are the karaf sources thought to be buildable by broader publicity (without setting custom repositories in settings.xml?)

Comment: Yes. You should be able to build the karaf sources from scratch. Sometimes  we have a SNAPSHOT dependency on the path that is not availble but this is normally only a temporary. The goal is that everyone should be able to build. Be aware though that the build is only tested on linux and mac. On windows it does not work most of the time as none of the committers uses windows for development.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139363/discussion-between-9ilsdx-9rvj-0lo-and-christian-schneider).

Answer (score 0):

Karaf creates the server key when you first connect using ssh. It will then place the key in karaf home etc/host.key. So the key should only be created once for each karaf server.

You can also provide your own key there to avoid the overhead of the creation.

The key is generated by org.apache.sshd.server.keyprovider.SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider. When it creates a key you should see this message in the log:

```
generateKeyPair(RSA) generating host key - size=4096
```

Comment: So this key should not be overwritten? If it is, what part of system is responsible for that? Is there any specific log message I should look for?

Comment: Yes. The key should only be created once.  Added some more info to the answer.

Comment: I've edited my question. It seems that host.key is ignored and something else is generating SSH keys on startup...

Comment: Missing classes: org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.BCRSAPrivateCrtKey

Who is responsible for providing that class: JRE environment, Karaf or specific Karaf feature?

Comment: Where do you get this error? In my system this package is not present in the karaf system.

Comment: I get this when running karaf via bin/start, when host.key exists.
How exactly do karaf get those security classes? Bouncycastle is installed on my karaf. It might change the way the java security functions. It should be transparent, unless someone makes unchecked casting. When using OpenSSH Generator I've got another exception, this time by writing: org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.BCRSAPrivateCrtKey cannot be cast to org.apache.commons.ssl.PEMItem

Comment: You have a JUnit test OpenSSHGeneratorKeyFileProviderTest, where there's a comment 'how would we tell if they read 'correctly'? Well, the base class will throw if the key isn't reasonable.'. Well, it's not true, the exceptions when parsing are logged out and a new key pair is generated. Therefore test passes, even if it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: I just created a second test with an empty .pem file. As overwrite is false karaf uses a one time key. As far as I can tell this works as designed. Not sure if this is a good idea though as it will be extremely slow. I would prefer to have a setting to use a key from a file and exit with an exception if the key is invalid. I opened an issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KARAF-5072

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KARAF-5073 After downloading the sources of not-yet-ssl-commons I'm pretty sure writing keys can't work. I don't know what code it was tested against because there are no sources of that library in maven, I've manually downloaded their trunk. 
I don't like as well OpenSSHGeneratorKeyFileProviderTest because they test only if something was read, the test should compare private and public key value. 
I'm unable to parse the .pem key with openssl command line, but my knowledge there is limited, maybe I do something wrong there.